# Error: type inference was unable to figure out the type. Getting error on upgrading scala version

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

```
logger.info("Error Response:[" + extraInfo.session("username").asOption[String]
                + "], Code:[" + statusCode + "], Response Body:[" + extraInfo.response.body.string
                + "], Token:[" + extraInfo.session("cspAuthToken").asOption[String]
                + "], Org id:[" + extraInfo.session("defaultOrgId").asOption[String]
                + "], Started At: [" + startedAt + "], Current time:[" + System.nanoTime()
                + "], Total Seconds:[" + totalSecondsPassed + "]")
```

This was code written in scala version 2.12.3 and later on upgrading scala version to version to 2.13.1 I getting this error as:

```
Sorry, type inference was unable to figure out the type. You need to provide it explicitly.
              logger.info("Error Response:[" + extraInfo.session("username").asOption[String]
```

Comment: What version of Gatling are you using?

Comment: I am using gatling version 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

gatling doesn't support scala 2.13 (see https://gatling.io/docs/current/installation)
(as of Gatling 3.3)